# Keep track of likes without a user login

Tags: javascript, node.js

The blog of my website allows liking the posts. But this is only for users who signup. So if some new user likes a blog post , I won’t be able to record his like .

My questions is how can I keep track whether a visitor has liked a blog or not without signing up ?

Comment: What do you mean like? Keep track how? You can gather IP adresses etc?

Comment: How should I make sure if an anonymous visitor has liked a post so that they can’t like a second time?

Comment: Any reason you can not use regular cookies?

Comment: They can be deleted. So technically a visitor can like multiple times. Also most IPs are dynamic so can’t use that either.

Comment: This is a know problem with no solution. If there was, advertisment firms would always know just who you are at all time. Cookies/localstorage is your best bet. Not perfect, but the only viable option.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could record their 'like' in a cookie so they can't (note 1) 'like' the same post more than once. You'd need to check for the cookie value of course.

Note 1: There's no guarantee that the user (or robot) has cookies enabled though, so it's impossible to stop multiple 'likes'. It depends how important this is to you.